# How to display relevant error messages in vee-validate

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, validation, vee-validate

How can I display error message that is relevant to the error in vee-validate. I have a number input and I validate it for required and numeric like so:

```
<ValidationObserver :name="'age'">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center">
          <h3 class="nunito text-2xl">Wpisz swój rok urodzenia</h3>

          <form class="" @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(onSubmit('alko'))">
            <label for="age" class="hidden">Wpisz swój rok urodzenia</label>
            <ValidationProvider
              v-slot="{ errors }"
              mode="eager"
              rules="numeric|required"
              :bails="false"
            >
              <input
                id="age"
                type="number"
                placeholder="1992"
                v-model="ageInput"
                name="age"
                data-vv-scope="alko"
                class="k-border p-4 text-center h-20 w-44 text-xl nunito my-6"
              />
              <div class="text-red-500 text-center nunito text-xs">
                {{ errors[0] }}
              </div>
            </ValidationProvider>
          </form>
        </div>
      </ValidationObserver>
```

```
<script>
import { ValidationProvider, ValidationObserver, extend } from "vee-validate";
import { numeric, required } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";
export default {
  name: "AgeVerificationXs",
  components: {
    ValidationProvider,
    ValidationObserver,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      showAlko: true,
      ageInput: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
  },
  created() {
    extend("required", {
      ...required,
      message: "To pole jest wymagane",
    });
    extend("numeric", {
      ...numeric,
      message: "To pole może zawierać tylko cyfry",
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

The thing is that when I enter non-numeric characters on Firefox (on chrome they're disabled by default in fields type number) the message I get is that this field is required, the thing is the field was filled and the rule that should be applied is "numeric" I display errors[0] (accordingly to the docs and every single example I have found) but I need to display error message relevant to the error. How can I do that? Appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that you have your "required" and "numeric" rules in the created() lifecycle hook. You need to move them up out of export default {} and the created() lifecycle hook and below where you are importing them, like this:

```
import { numeric, required } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";

extend("required", {
  ...required,
  message: "To pole jest wymagane",
});
extend("numeric", {
  ...numeric,
  message: "To pole może zawierać tylko cyfry",
});
```